# Realm. Project builds but doesn't archive. iOS 12, Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I have the following problem:

Xcode 11.2
Swift 5
iOS 12

My app can build, and runs in the simulator with no problems.
When archiving, I get the following error:

> error: /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-fkxpkymhgqkjtidvkhxdkylinmof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MY_APP/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Realm.framework: No such file or directory

and

> error: /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MY_APP-fkxpkymhgqkjtidvkhxdkylinmof/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MY_APP/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Realm.framework: No such file or directory

After reading several posts on the subject, I have tried different approaches in the Framework Search Paths, but with no luck so far.

Also before builds I will need to clear the derived data folder, in order to make that work.

Very thankful for helpful suggestion!

Thanks

Palle

Comment: What realm version are you using?

Comment: Hi Jay, I'm using Realm 4.0.0

Comment: To clarify -  the app builds and runs in the simulator but does not run on the device?